# Unchecked cast warnings with parameterized types

Tags: java, generics, casting, warnings, unchecked

I am reading about restrictions on generics from the Java Tutorials, specifically [casting with parameterized types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast). I understand the examples that are presented. However, I am unsure about the following example:

```
List<? extends Number> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// unchecked cast warning
ArrayList<Number> l2 = (ArrayList<Number>) l1;
// no unchecked cast warning
ArrayList<? extends Number> l3 = (ArrayList<? extends Number>) l1;
```

I understand why there is a warning in the first case. Why is there no warning in the second case? Is it because the only operations that I can perform on `l3` are safe (e.g., I cannot add (say) a `Float` to the list)?

---

**UPDATE:** Below is an excerpt from [section 5.5.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2) that addresses similar questions.

> A cast from a type `S` to a parameterized type (§4.5) `T` is unchecked
>   unless at least one of the following is true:
>
> - `S <: T`
> - All of the type arguments (§4.5.1) of `T` are unbounded wildcards
> - `T <: S` and `S` has no subtype `X` other than `T` where the type arguments of `X` are not contained in the type arguments of `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no warning because the cast doesn't change the generic part of the type. `List<? extends Number>` and `ArrayList<? extends Number>` have the same type argument. Instead, the cast is a checked cast from `List` to `ArrayList`.